# Jquery select behavior differ on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple code:

```
    <input id="thisInput" class="MyInput"
                maxlength="3"
                value=" 0"
                type="text" />
```

and JS code:

```
$("#thisInput").on( "click", function() {
  $(this).select();
});
```

In Chrome this code. In first click selects all values in input. The other click end with no selection
In IE11 each click end with selection of all text in input.

my code is somewhat wrong? Or Chrome or IE is bugged?
[JSFIDDLe](http://jsfiddle.net/jn3o8cbL/)

Comment: that is why chrome is better than IE browsers. Although they have their own implementations of specific methods.

Comment: _"that is why chrome is better than IE browsers"_ - I'm not loyal to any browser, but that just isn't entirely accurate. Almost every browser comes with their advantages and disadvantages; it all comes down to user preference, and I can easily understand why some people would want a recent release of IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like [@Jai commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628313/jquery-select-behavior-differ-on-ie#comment45557047_28628313), this is the Chrome behavior. Personally I don't consider this a Chrome bug nor a IE one.

### Selecting the text always

If you want to always select the text from input, you can trick it with an async call:

```js
$("#thisInput").on("click", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).select();
  }.bind(this), 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="thisInput" class="MyInput" maxlength="3" value=" 0" type="text" />
```

#### Toggle selection

Well, the best working solution I see is using a flag and toggling it:

```js
var select = false;
$("#thisInput").on("click", function() {
  if (select = !select) {
    $(this).select();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="thisInput" class="MyInput" maxlength="3" value=" 0" type="text" />
```

Comment: Just the opposite. I want to reproduce chrome behaviour in IE.

Comment: @szpic Updated my answer. This will toggle selection.

Answer (score 1):

It may happened that click event is not triggering properly in IE, so try adding `focus` event also

```
$("#thisInput").on( "click focus", function() {
  $(this).select();
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jn3o8cbL/1/)**